# Widget to show number of installs on my app in the Google play store

Tags: android, rss, android-widget, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am working on finding a way to make a widget for my Android device to show the number of installs I have on my Android app. So far my idea is to make an app that reads information from the Google play console but I can't find any way to get that information. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

Google play does not offer any official APIs to get that information, but you can use third party APIs for that if you want to.

One example is [apptweak](https://apptweak.io).

Answer (score 0):

For similar needs you can use unofficial api that is [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/) on google codes.

it can be used to retrieve app details and other android market data. like :

```
>You can browse market with any carrier or locale you want.
>Search for apps using keywords or package name.
>Retrieve an app info using an app ID.
>Retrieve comments using an app ID.
>Get PNG screenshots and icon
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already [an official Google Play console app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole) that offers this information and a lot more.

It doesn't have a widget, but you could contact the developers to ask for one. I sit near them so I'll mention the request.